# Recompose when Clipboard contents change

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, clipboard

Jetpack Compose has a [ClipboardManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/platform/ClipboardManager), allowing us to get or set the value on the clipboard. I notice however that `getText()` does not return a `State`, or any observable value.

```
@Composable fun ClipboardContents() {
  val cb = LocalClipboardManager.current
  Text(cb.getText())
}
```

How can I make sure that my `Composable` function responds to changes in the Clipboard?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create `State<AnnotatedString>` that will be updated each time `ClipboardManager` clip has changed. This doesn't come out of the box you have to implement a functions that will observe for primary clip changes, then utilize that to create a state object that will trigger the recomposition.

```
@Composable
fun rememberClipboardText(): State<AnnotatedString?> {
    val clipboardManager = LocalClipboardManager.current
    val text = remember { mutableStateOf(clipboardManager.getText()) }
    onClipDataChanged {
        text.value = clipboardManager.getText()
    }
    return text
}

@SuppressLint("ComposableNaming")
@Composable
fun onClipDataChanged(onPrimaryClipChanged: ClipData?.() -> Unit) {
    val clipboardManager =
        LocalContext.current.getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE) as ClipboardManager
    val callback = remember {
        ClipboardManager.OnPrimaryClipChangedListener {
            onPrimaryClipChanged(clipboardManager.primaryClip)
        }
    }
    DisposableEffect(clipboardManager) {
        clipboardManager.addPrimaryClipChangedListener(callback)
        onDispose {
            clipboardManager.removePrimaryClipChangedListener(callback)
        }
    }
}
```

then the usage will be something like this:

```
@Composable
fun ClipboardContents() {
    val clipBoardText by rememberClipboardText()
    clipBoardText?.let { Text(it) }
}
```

Comment: This kind of information should be stored inside a viewModel. It will also eliminate the need to implement the `remember` logic since it's never completely safe in Compose anyway.

Comment: That's not necessarily true. Why would they expose  `LocalClipboardManager` then?

Comment: Just why they created a `remember` composable. They're giving you the option to create state within a Composable, but urge you to keep the Composables stateless.

Comment: You are allowed to have stateful caller site and pass the data to the stateless composables.

Comment: Obviously, the calling site at the top of the hierarchy **has** to be stateful. I don't see your point, good sir.

Answer (score 0):

All the important info, i.e., business logic that your app depends on should be inside a lifecycle aware component like a ViewModel, not in a `remember`ed state inside an `@Composable` invocation. This ensures proper disposal of the resources when the app is destroyed, and above everything keeps your data secure.

Have a var initialised and observed inside a viewModel like so

```
var clipText by mutableStateOf<String?>(null)
fun initialiseModel(context) {
  // Do the stuff you want
  ...
  with(context.getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE) as ClipboardManager) {
    addPrimaryClipChangedListener{
      clipText = getText().toStrint()
    }
  }
}
```

There may be a cleverer way, but I'm typing this on a mobile device, so can't experiment.

Petition for a Compose Playground app to run composable code on the fly,